# Integrate Flickity With Bootstrap 4 Carousel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flickity

I start using **[Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com)** yesterday, and I exploring [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co) last week. Now I just try to integrate Flickity with my Bootstrap 4 using the quick [Bootrap 4 examples](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/) and I'm using the **[carousel](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/)**. But when I add the Flickity with the built-in carousel the following has been dis-arranged, mis-aligned or any called with it. **But I want to use the existing designs of the Bootstrap 4 example carousel not even using the Flickity carousel controller  I just need to add Flickity to add touch, reponsive, and flickible carousels.** The following codes I used below.

```css
/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */


/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */


/* Carousel base class */

.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}


/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */

.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 3rem;
}


/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */

.carousel-item {
  height: 32rem;
  background-color: #777;
}

.carousel-item>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 32rem;
}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */


/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */

.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 5rem 0;
  /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}


/* Thin out the marketing headings */

.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -.05rem;
}


/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 7rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" data-flickity='{ "autoPlay": true }'>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/382686/pexels-photo-382686.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="First slide" style="height: 100%">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/249023/pexels-photo-249023.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/362690/pexels-photo-362690.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-right">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: You need to pick either Flickity or Bootstrap's carousel plugin to use. You can't throw them together and expect them to work.

Comment: https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made an [issue](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/551) at Metafizzy Flickity Github repository to ask the owner Mr. Desandro about the problem in integrating Flickity with Bootstrap 4 carousel.

Then he replied:

> "we cannot use both Bootstrap carousel and Flickity at the same time. They are two separate solutions for the same feature. I recommend you choose either one or the other. You can use some of the interior carousel Bootstrap CSS like carousel-caption within a Flickity carousel."

Then he gave the following demonstration located [at Codepen](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/0b21742d14871f88a56893eeee7011c7/). The copy of the code is found below.

```css
.carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #777;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-cell .container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="flickity-carousel" data-flickity='{ "autoPlay": true }'>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block text-left">
        <h1>Example headline.</h1>
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
        <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block text-right">
        <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```